# regarding difference between sharepoint server and biz talk server.which one good to learn

Tags: sharepoint-2007, biztalk2006r2

hi every iam willing to learn advance to .net language ,so someone suggested me to do biztalk server ,some one  told to do sharepointserver iam totally confused what to do .so plz some one  tell me difference between both and which is good in the sence of oputunities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what your goals are.  These two products are VERY different and have VERY different purposes.  If you're a web developer, then you should look at SharePoint. We recently released SharePoint 2010 which offers some AMAZING developer tools in VS2010 compared to previous versions.  If, instead, you're more of a middleware type of person, then BizTalk might be your way to go. BizTalk makes use of WF and WCF extensively, so those are also good skills to know before getting in.

Cheers!
Chris